# Mathematical functions to calculate possibilities

Tags: c#, math

I'm working on a sort of math function where I have to check which of two lists are bigger and cannot be overtaken anymore.

I've been working on this for quite some time but I can't really get it right and the code is becoming complex to me. I'm thinking that there is some sort of formula which is available to make my life easier but I can't find it and I'm afraid mathmatics is not my strong point.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I've got two lists to which a value of 0 or 1 is added every other step. So step 1 adds a 0 or 1 to List1, Step 2 adds a 0 or 1 to List 2.

After 6 steps the function has to stop and check if List 1 have more ones inside then List 2 or vice versa. It may also be equal.

But when for example you're at step 4 and List 1 has two ones inside and List 2 has two zeroes inside, then the function should stop and Show List1 because List 2 can never surpass or equalise List 1 anymore.

Another example:
If you're in step 5 and List1 has 1 one and 2 zeroes and List2 has 2 ones than the function should stop because it doesn't matter anymore because List2 has more ones than List1.

But I can't seem to solve this puzzle. Is there anyone out there that can figure this out?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resetLists();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nextStep();
}

public Random rnd = new Random();
public List<int> List1 = new List<int>();
public List<int> List2 = new List<int>();
public int step = 0;

private void resetLists()
{
    List1.Clear();
    List2.Clear();
    step = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
}

private void nextStep()
{
    step++;

    if (step <= 6)
    {
        if (step % 2 != 0)
        {
            int result = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            List1.Add(result);
            Console.WriteLine("List 1: " + result.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            int result = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            List2.Add(result);
            Console.WriteLine("List 2: " + result.ToString());
        }

        if (step > 3)
        {
            checkLists();
        }
    }
}

private void checkLists()
{
    int actualResultList1 = 0;
    int actualResultList2 = 0;
    int virtualResultList1 = 0;
    int virtualResultList2 = 0;

    // GET THE ONES FROM LIST 1
    for (int l1 = 0; l1 < List1.Count; l1++)
    {
        if (List1[l1] == 1)
        {
            actualResultList1++;
        }
    }

    // GET THE ONES FROM LIST 2
    for (int l2 = 0; l2 < List2.Count; l2++)
    {
        if (List2[l2] == 1)
        {
            actualResultList2++;
        }
    }

    // CALCULUATE THE VIRTUAL ONES
    virtualResultList1 = 3 - List1.Count;
    virtualResultList2 = 3 - List2.Count;

    if (step < 6)
    {
        if ((actualResultList1 + virtualResultList1) >= (actualResultList2 + virtualResultList2) + (6-step))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("List1");
        }

        if ((actualResultList2 + virtualResultList2) >= (actualResultList1 + virtualResultList1) + (6-step))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("List2");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (actualResultList1 > actualResultList2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("List1");
        }
        else if (actualResultList2 > actualResultList1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("List2");
        }
        else if (actualResultList1 == actualResultList2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're adding `1` or `0`, to count the `1`s you can simply use `List1.Sum()`. Your question about stopping early is dealing with `best of x` vs `first to x`. If you're running 6 steps, then you have a `best of 6` situation. To convert `best of n` to `first to n`, you can run: `(n + 1)/2`. And compare if it's *greater or equal*. If you have 6 steps, you can stop if either list's count is `>= (6 + 1) / 2` (which in this case is 3.5, so 4 satisfies this).

Comment: Sorry, I misread - to detect if you can exit early, the difference between each list must be greater than the number of steps left. For example: `Math.Abs(List1.Count() - List2.Count()) > (numSteps - currentStep)` will tell you if either list has immediately won. Your example about step for doesn't work, though - List1 can gain two 1s, List2 could gain two 0s, and they'd both end up with 2 on step 6.

Comment: Step4 is the earliest exitpoint: if List 1 has 2 ones and List 2 at that point gets it 2nd 0, then List2 can never equalise again because each list only has one step left.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right - I missed the 'every other' step. In that case you'd divide the right side (`numSteps - currentSteps`) by `2`

Comment: I'm trying but I can't get it to work... What am I doing wrong? if (Math.Abs(actualResultList1 - actualResultList2) > ((6 - step)/2))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("List1");
                }  In the 4th step when List2 has 2 ones and List1 has 2 zeroes, it should exit but in this case I have 2 on the left side of the equasion and 3 on the other siode

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You're not setting `step` properly then - the right side `(6 - 4) / 2` should have `1`

Comment: You were right, I wasn't setting Step right, but when I try this: if (Math.Abs(actualResultList1 - actualResultList2) > ((6 - step) / 2)) and actualresultlist1 is 0 and actualresultlist2 is 2 and step is 4, it exits the function too eventhough the equasion is -2 > 1, which isn't right. I'm guessing it has something to do with the Math.Abs?

Comment: ah wait, I think I understand. The abs returns an absolute number regardless if it's negative. But then how do I figure out which list is the "winner"?

Comment: The `Abs` method takes the *absolute* value of the number. In this case, it converts `-2` to `2`. The idea behind the check is that `-2` still means the difference between the number of `1`s is still 2, which is greater than the number of steps each: 1. So it's valid to exit

Comment: Ofcourse, just by checking which actualresult is bigger

Comment: You'd find the winner after early-exiting - since you don't want to duplicate that code. You can find out who wins later by checking which has the larger number after finishing. `var listOneWins = ListOne.Sum() > ListTwo.Sum()` - for example

Comment: I'm just testing and I see another issue: List1 = 0-1-1 and List2 = 0-1 and I'm in Step 5, but it exits eventhough List2 might still equalise...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it thanks to the great help given by Rob.

The final solution:

```
private void checkLists()
{
int actualResultList1 = 0;
int actualResultList2 = 0;

// GET THE ONES FROM LIST 1
for (int l1 = 0; l1 < List1.Count; l1++)
{
    if (List1[l1] == 1)
    {
        actualResultList1++;
    }
}

// GET THE ONES FROM LIST 2
for (int l2 = 0; l2 < List2.Count; l2++)
{
    if (List2[l2] == 1)
    {
        actualResultList2++;
    }
}

if ((List1.Count + List2.Count) < 6)
{
    if (actualResultList1 > (actualResultList2 + ((6/2) - List2.Count)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("List1");
    }

    if (actualResultList2 > (actualResultList1 + ((6/2) - List1.Count)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("List2");
    }
}
else
{
    if (actualResultList1 > actualResultList2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("List1");
    }
    else if (actualResultList2 > actualResultList1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("List2");
    }
    else if (actualResultList1 == actualResultList2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("equal");
    }
}
}
```

So if somebody in the future is also looking for this, here it is.